# Create Custom Repository Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I need to create a repository in order to find the specified records (names) in the table.

```
class CategoryRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getAllByName($name)
    {
        return  $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT * FROM AppBundle\Entity\Category WHERE name LIKE "$name"');
    }
}
```

I did so, but, unfortunately, it does not work. Tell me, please, how can I do this?
MySQL Query need be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE name LIKE 'Your_Name'
```

Comment: There's no point in the `LIKE` in that query. Just use `=`. But if you use `=`, you could just use `$entities = $repo->findByName($name);` Also, the `FROM` should be the _entity_ class, not the repository.

Comment: You're probably also missing quotes around the `$name` value, but you should be using parameters anyway, not concatenating values into the query.

Comment: @JonStirling, something like this?
`return  $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT * FROM AppBundle\Entity\Category WHERE name = "$name"');`

Comment: Kind of, except that's still not using parameters. My suggestion is just don't use your own method. Where you're currently calling `getAllByName`, just call `findByName($name)`, which is dealt with by Doctrine's EntityRepository.

Comment: @JonStirling, writes: Method 'findByName($name)' not found in repository...

Comment: @JonStirling, did and it worked: `$result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findBy(array('name' => '$name'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `doctrine query builder`.
In you method `getAllByName()` add follow code:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

return $qb
        ->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->like('c.name', ':search'),
        )
        ->setParameter('search', "%$search%")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

With this method you can use `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

probably you miss the call at the getResult() method on the query object as example:

```
/**
 * @return Category[]
 */
 public function getAllByName($name)
{
    return  $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT * FROM AppBundle\Entity\Category WHERE name LIKE "$name"')->getResult();
}
```

Some info [here in the doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/reference/query.html#the-query-object)

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Working method:

```
$result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findBy(array('name' => '$name'));
```